# Multiple OR and AND conditions in pySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, pipeline

I'm trying to achieve result for following logic

```
IF Text.Contains([Col1] = "Text1" OR [Col1] = "Text2"))
AND 
Text.Contains([Col3] = "Text3")) AND
(IF not (Text.Contains([Col2] ="12345") OR
not Text.Contains([Col2] = "67890"))
```

I wrote following code in pySpark but Im not getting desired results

```
(
    (F.col("Col1").like("%Text1%") | F.col("Col1").like("%Text2"))
    &
    (
        (F.col("Col3").like("%Text3%")) &
        (~F.col("Col2").like("%12345%") | (~F.col("Col2").like("%67890%")))
    )
)
```

Will someone please help me correct the code to get the desired results?

My input dataset is:

| Col1 | Col3 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Text1; Random | Text3; Random | 12345;67890;34567 |
| Random; Text2 | Text3 | 98765;54321 |

So The expected output is a Boolean result where False is expected for 1st row whereas True is expected for 2nd row.

Comment: I think you're missing paretheses around the last OR, or the last AND should be outside of the parentheses.

Comment: I just did, but still incorrect results

Comment: Please add your input dataset and expected output alongwith the use case, this will help the forum provide better solution.

Comment: @DipanjanMallick I've added my input dataset

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, this is what you're trying to achieve:

```py
(
    F.col("Col1").like("%Text1%") | F.col("Col1").like("%Text2")
)
&
F.col("Col3").like("%Text3%")
&
(
    (~F.col("Col2").like("%12345%")) | (~F.col("Col2").like("%67890%"))
)
```

Comment: No, this is still giving incorrect result. My condition is Col1 should contain either of Text1 OR Text 2 AND Col3 should contain Text3 AND Col2 should not have any of '12345' OR '67890'

Comment: Your snippets made that unclear, but this should be what you're after

Comment: I've added the input dataset, your solution still gives True for both the cases. I expect False for 1st entry in my dataset as per my logic.

Comment: It should be `False` for both examples, as column 2 and 3 are the wrong way around.

Comment: For second row, Col1 has ‘Text2’ (condition satisfied) AND Col3 has ‘Text3’ (condition satisfied) AND Col2 has none of 12345 OR 67890, hence the output should be TRUE but for first row Col3 has 12345 and hence output should be FALSE. But I'm getting TRUE for both the entries.

Comment: Are we looking at the same example? Col3 _definitely_ doesn't contain Text3 anywhere.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I've updated the source table input this time as Col3 has string values and Col2 has numerical values.